# Javacsript for loop in for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I want to use for loop in for loop.
With comment(first loop) work fine. it display "012345".
but without comment, it just display "0" and

> "ReferenceError: i_i is not defined" error.

What wrong with my loop?

```
<script>
    var str = "123456";
    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) 
    {
        document.write(i);
        /*without comment, doesn't work
        for(var i_1 = 0; i_i < str.length; i_1++)
        {
            document.write(i_1);
        }*/
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You have typo in `i_i < str.length;` should be `i_1 < str.length;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in the second for loop.

```
i_i < str.length
```

should be

```
i_1 < str.length
```

You've got an `i` instead of a `1`

Comment: You should flag questions like this as a typo, rather that answering them. Answering off-topic questions can motivate another users writing more off-topic questions.

Comment: Will do in the future.  And thanks for cleaning it up.